# Phonegap APK expansion with com.flyingsoftgames.xapkreader plugin

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, apk-expansion-files

I'm having troubles with APK expansion management in a Phonegap application on Android platform.

I installed the [com.flyingsoftgames.xapkreader](https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-xapkreader) phonegap plugin and following all the instructions I managed to upload the first APK along with its expansion `.obb` file.
The first download from the Play Store worked just fine: the app and its extras were successfully downloaded to the device with a single operation.

After publishing an update of the APK and downloading it to the device, the following happened:

1. I launched the updated application;
2. The downloader activity of the [com.flyingsoftgames.xapkreader](https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-xapkreader) started, showing the download dialog;
3. Since the `.obb` file didn't change and a copy of it was already present in the local folder, the downloader activity read "*Download completed.*";
4. Finally the problem is that the dialog was not dismissed, nor it presents any way to dismiss it manually, so the application doesn't proceed with its launching.
5. The only way to launch it, is to kill it (in order to stop the "stuck" download activity) and opening it again.

Should I provide a different `.obb` for each updated version? I don't think so, since this would invalidate the APK+OBB mechanism, conceived to allow for smaller sized updates, as far as I have understood.

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it seemed like a bad installation of the plugin.
I resolved by *removing* all plugins, *rebulding* the application for the desired platform from scratch (e.g. `phonegap build android`) and by *re-installing* all the plugins.

I noticed something strange though: the installation of the plugin via phonegap plugin installer (with command `phonegap plugins add com.flyingsoftgames.xapkreader`) installs a different version than the one from the github repository (with the command `phonegap plugin add https://github.com/agamemnus/cordova-plugin-xapkreader.git`).
So pay attention in case you find different instructions in tutorials and forums.
The version that worked for me was the one from the github repository.